# Is it possible to open an app in a small window WITHIN my own app?

Tags: android

Currently I am trying to build my school project in Android and I am afraid I have chosen a really difficult project to complete. I would ask if it is possible to open a 3rd party application in a small window within my application. When I try to start a 3rd party application via a button click, the application starts and I cannot go back to my application any more. I want to start another application IN my application, take a screenshot of it, and close this small window.  I would kindly ask you to help me in this subject. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: It's possible but it won't be a school project anymore, assume. https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/index.html

Answer (score 3):

> I would ask if it is possible to open a 3rd party application in a small window within my application

No, sorry.

> I want to start another application IN my application, take a screenshot of it, and close this small window

You can start an activity via `startActivity()`. With user permission, you can take a screenshot of whatever is on the screen, by means of the media projection APIs. You cannot:

- embed the UI of the other activity in yours
- open the other activity in a "small window" (though the user could, using split-screen capabilities in Android 7.0+)

Comment: In the end, I decided to use multiwindow.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the day, I decided to use multiwindow. Adding the line below into my code, I made it to run in a small window. Then I was able to start the other activity in the big window.